# Angular Material error when use with Browserify

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel-5, angular-material

I use Browserify all the js files but it produce this error when run in browser

```
Error: [jqLite:nosel] Looking up elements via selectors is not supported by jqLite! See: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element
```

and here is the whole HTML blade of Laravel

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <md-content>
        <md-toolbar>
            <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
                <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Settings">
                    <md-icon md-svg-icon="/img/logo.jpg"></md-icon>
                </md-button>
                <h2><span class="md-title">Service Rocket</span></h2>
            </div>
        </md-toolbar>
        {{-- The content area --}}
        <div layout="row">
        {{-- 20% padding to the left --}}
            <div flex="20"></div>
            {{-- The main action happens here --}}
            <md-card flex ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl">
                <md-card-content>
                    <!-- The row for the city select autocomplete list -->
                    <md-content layout-padding="">
                        <form>
                            <md-input-container flex="" class="md-icon-float">
                                <label>Name</label>
                                <md-icon md-svg-icon="/img/action/svg/production/ic_face_48px.svg"></md-icon>                                   
                                <input type="text" name="appname" id="appname" ng-model="applicant.name">
                            </md-input-container>
                            <md-input-container flex="" class="md-icon-float">
                                <label>Email</label>
                                <md-icon md-svg-icon="/img/communication/svg/production/ic_quick_contacts_mail_48px.svg"></md-icon>
                                <input type="email" name="appemail" id="appemail" ng-model="applicant.email">
                            </md-input-container>
                            <md-input-container flex="">
                                <label>Biography</label>
                                <textarea id="appbio" name="appbio" ng-model="applicant.about" maxlength="150"></textarea>
                            </md-input-container>                           
                            <md-button>
                                <label for="appdocs">Resume</label>
                            </md-button>
                            <input type="file" name="appdocs" id="appdocs">
                            <div layout>
                                <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="submit()">Submit my application</md-button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </md-content>
                    {{-- The submit button --}}
                </md-card-content>
            </md-card>
            <div flex="20"></div>
        </div>
    </md-content>
<script src="{{ asset('/js/bundle.js') }}"></script>
</body>
```

For your information I use Laravel-elixir browserify to manage its concatenations. Is there anyone experience this

Comment: If you can create a fiddle to see the actual problem maybe i can help!

Comment: Though, i would suggest you stop using the Laravel's HTML/Form Builders, as these are deprecated..

Comment: i use the laravel  collective. It's active one. I cannot create a fiddle because the js file too big to load on jsfiddle

Comment: First thing I see: looks like you want `md-svg-src` instead of `md-svg-icon`

Answer (score 0):

If anyone ever experience this. IMHO, just delete the `node_modules` folder and run `npm install` again. Weird issue can happen during installation because the network may intermittent.